# Start Emacs from MobXterm

Tags: cygwin, emacs, mobaxterm

I was using Emacs for a while from Cygwin. I created a link shortcut on Desktop and started it from there.
Now I want to try Emacs from MobaXterm. I installed Emacs package but can't figure out how to start it from my PC with one click.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard my question.
I was able to find solution myself.
I simply created a shortcut on Desktop and pointed to emacs executable.

Thanks